# Certain Firebase data only showing when page is reloaded

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Everything is working fine for the following Firebase database query, except the reordering function (basic reordering of dictionaries into arrays I then use) does not work on initial load.

If I then navigate away from the page and back to it (triggering a reload), everything is presented nicely re-ordered. I've tried moving the function around, but I haven't had much luck. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
refHandle = ref.child("users/\(uid ?? "x")").child("Selections").observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

    self.userOriginalMenus.append(snapshot.key)
    let rightDict = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

    for dictName in rightDict.allKeys {

        self.userTitlesToDisplay.append(dictName as! String)
        let selectionDict = rightDict[dictName] as! NSDictionary

        for selectionName in selectionDict.allKeys {

            let index = selectionDict[selectionName]

            let selectionNumberString = index as! String
            let actualSelectionNumber = Int(selectionNumberString)
            self.userDict[actualSelectionNumber!] = "\(selectionName)"
            self.userTitlesToDisplayDict[actualSelectionNumber!] = "\(dictName)"
            self.userOriginalMenusDict[actualSelectionNumber!] = snapshot.key
        }
    }
    self.reorderSelections()
})
```

Comment: My first thought is if this is related to authentication. Are you perhaps attaching the observer before the user is authenticated?

Comment: Thanks for your help Frank! I don't think so re authentication. Im finding it difficult in general to display items from my Firebase database that need to be re-ordered by their values. For example a list of items and their user count (ordered alphabetically by item name in Firebase) - how would I order these by their user count? Again, I can do it easily after a page reload, but can't get it inside the initial data retrieval to be displayed in the right order in collection views etc on first load. Thanks again.

Comment: I think I've got this now by using ordered query, but still cant get the first one to load right, where data is coming from 2 queries and then being reordered.